# Using bitwise logic to test Control.MouseButtons

Tags: c#, winforms

Can someone kindly explain how this works?

```
if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
```

MSDN only says that Control.MouseButtons Property gets a value indicating which of the mouse buttons is in a pressed state but I can't understand how that '&' works and why should it be different than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MouseButtons` property is a bit flag vs. a normal enum.  That means it can simultaneously hold values like `MouseButtons.Left` and `MouseButtons.Right`.  It does this by using the `1 / 0` states of specific bits within the value to represent states.  `MouseButtons.Left` and `MouseButtons.Right` represent such states.

The `&` operation is known as `bitwise and`.  It will return a value which has the bits which were `1` in both the left and the right value.  Hence this particular expression will only be non-zero when the `MouseButtons.Left` bit is set in `MouseButtons` meaning that the left button is indeed pressed

Comment: ECXELLENT! Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1):

[Control.MouseButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons.aspx) is a bitwise combination.

The expression:

```
if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
```

is checking if the bit `MouseButtons.Left` is set (has value 1).